# xtable inside of a for loop in Rmarkdown is printing {} in output when floating = FALSE

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, xtable

I am trying to create an Rmarkdown file with a loop to print several tables.

For example, this Rmarkdown file:

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document

---


```{r, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE}


library(dplyr)
library(xtable)


```


```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}

for(i in unique(mtcars$gear)){

mtcars %>%
  filter(gear == i) %>%
    select(-gear) -> tmp

table <- xtable(tmp)


print(table, 
      size="footnotesize", 
      include.rownames = TRUE,
      comment = FALSE, 
      floating = FALSE)

}
```
````

Produces a pdf with three tables, but it has {} included in the output:

[image: pdf example image]

If I remove the floating = FALSE option the braces are not present in the output. However, I will be using this code with longtables which require floating = TRUE.

How can I exclude the braces from the pdf output when floating = FALSE ?